# Did Neanderthals have a soul? From when do people exists/have soul?

Tags: souls, evolution

Does the church agree with some kind of Darwin evolution and big bang theory? If so, from when does human exists? If we think of human as we have soul, did Neanderthals had one? Was it like this individual does not have soul yet but from now, his children do have a soul and are the first people that could go to heaven?

Comment: Please ask one question.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  Please take our Tour to see how we are different to other sites and what we look for in well-researched questions.  We try to avoid questions that invite opinion-based answers, and you may need to edit your question and add some tags to narrow down the scope.  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Is soul equals to ruach?

Comment: What do you mean by "the church"? Some Christian denominations don't even believe that Homo sapiens "have souls". You need to specify a specific religion; "Christianity" isn't a single organization with uniform beliefs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Did Neanderthals have a soul? From when do people exists/have soul?**

Do animals have souls like human beings?

The Catholic Church teaches that animals may have mortal souls whereas modern man (after Adam and his descendants) has an **immortal soul**!

Do animals have souls? Do plants have plant souls? Although not a defined dogma, it is permitted for Catholics to believe Neanderthals may have possessed an animal, yet mortal soul only.

The soul is the principle of life. Since animals and plants are living things, they have souls, but not in the sense in which human beings have souls. Our souls are rational–theirs aren’t–and ours are rational because they’re spiritual, not material.

Animals and plants can’t do anything which transcends the limitations of matter. Although some animals seem clever, they don’t actually possess conceptional intelligence. They can’t, for instance, conceive of the abstract notion of justice.

> Most people have experienced the sadness of witnessing an animal die, usually a beloved pet who brought great joy throughout their short lifespan. During the grieving period, it’s common for parents to tell children that there’s a special place for all the animals who have departed from their world – like a pet heaven.
>
> This image of a pet no longer in pain and experiencing paradise can certainly alleviate the worry of a young child wondering where their favourite animal has gone to, but is there any truth to the claim?
>
> The Church has no official teaching on the matter of pets entering heaven, but there are theological principles that can direct us to what answer is most probable.
>
> Catholics believe that all living things have souls, and this includes not only humans, but also plants and animals. When a living thing dies, the soul separates from its body or organic makeup. In the case of animals, the soul goes out of existence. However, the souls of human beings are radically different from the souls of other living things. Whereas the souls of animals are contingent upon their material makeup, human souls remain in existence after death because it is immaterial.
>
> This means that that human souls can’t be destroyed, and so are immortal.
>
> **Reasonable**
>
> Pope Emeritus Benedict XVI said in a sermon in 2008, that when an animal dies, it “just means the end of existence on earth”. It’s reasonable to believe then that all animals that die before the Second Coming and the creation of the “new heaven and new earth” will cease to exist.
>
> This, however, doesn’t necessarily mean that there won’t be any animals after the Second Coming.
>
> Some theologians argue that animals flourished in the Garden of Eden, before sin entered the world, and so there’s no inherent or theological contradiction in positing that God could create more animals.Animals were present when the fullness of grace abounded. However, others argue that there will be no need for animals to exist in the new creation, which pertains to ultimately knowing and loving God. Of course, this is all just speculative, and we will only really ever find out the answer at the end of time.
>
> > “The souls of human beings are radically different from the souls of other living things”
>
> [Do animals go to heaven?](https://www.irishcatholic.com/do-animals-go-to-heaven/)

Ultimately, this question should deal with the prospect of whether or not the Neanderthals had the intellectual ability to worship God. In other words were the Neanderthals more animal like or human like?

For those who believe in evolution, the Catholic Church allows the faithful to believe in this theory. The Church equally makes some qualitative point that are to be observe in this domain.

It is equally impermissible to dismiss the story of Adam and Eve and the fall (Gen. 2–3) as a fiction. A question often raised in this context is whether the human race descended from an original pair of two human beings (a teaching known as monogenism) or a pool of early human couples (a teaching known as polygenism).

In this regard, Pope Pius XII stated:

> “When, however, there is question of another conjectural opinion, namely polygenism, the children of the Church by no means enjoy such liberty. For the faithful cannot embrace that opinion which maintains either that after Adam there existed on this earth true men who did not take their origin through natural generation from him as from the first parents of all, or that Adam represents a certain number of first parents. Now, it is in no way apparent how such an opinion can be reconciled that which the sources of revealed truth and the documents of the teaching authority of the Church proposed with regard to original sin which proceeds from a sin actually committed by an individual Adam in which through generation is passed onto all and is in everyone as his own” (Humani Generis 37).

In other words, either Adam and Eve were created as the Scriptures literally tells us or Adam and Eve somehow evolved from some preexisting humanoid form such as the Neanderthals. Only Adam and Eve along with their descendants were infused with the gift of an immortal and rational soul. **Thus Neanderthals would not have possessed an *immortal soul*! They simply possessed a *mortal soul* like that of any other animal lower in dignity than man.**

> Thou hast made him a little lower than the angels: thou hast crowned him with glory and honour, and hast set him over the works of thy hands. - [Hebrews 2:7](https://biblehub.com/hebrews/2-7.htm)

[image: The human lineage of Australopithecus afarensis, Homo habilis, Homo erectus, Neanderthals and Homo sapiens.]

[The human lineage of  Australopithecus afarensis, Homo habilis, Homo erectus, Neanderthals and Homo sapiens.](https://www.history.com/news/humans-evolution-neanderthals-denisovans)

Although they say nothing is written in stone, with the exemption of the **Ten Commandments** written by God, there is lots of room for debate on this issue of human evolution. This is just one perspective.

Just today the news made headlines:

- [Remains of nine Neanderthals found in cave south of Rome](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2021/may/08/remains-of-nine-neanderthals-found-in-cave-south-of-rome) May 8, 2021.

My personal dilemma is whether the Sasquatch (Bigfoot) a living relic of the [Neanderthal](https://www.amazon.ca/Bigfoot-Yeti-Last-Neanderthal-Geneticistss/dp/193887515X)???

Comment: @MigueldeServet The vast majority of Christians believe that when a person dies their souls live on in either heaven or hell. Ergo their souls are immortal and do not die when our bodies die! As for my last statement there are some that genuinely believe that the [Sasquatch](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/bigfoot-yeti-and-the-last-neanderthal-bryan-sykes/1122693099?ean=9781633410275) may indeed be a relic of the Neanderthal Age!

Comment: Your comment is in response to a comment of mine that was obviously removed. So your comment sticks out like a sore thumb ...

Comment: @MigueldeServet Absolutely not. Pax.

Comment: It is no good denying the obvious evidence :(

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

> Does the church agree with some kind of Darwin evolution and big bang theory?

Many Christians, even entire church organizations, have unfortunately succumbed to pressure from anti-Christian, anti-theistic Uniformitarian "scientists" to deny the Creation that is taught in Genesis 1. (The entire basis of Uniformitarian / Naturalist "science" is "there is no God"; all of their claims ultimately derive from this dogma.)

Some Christians still believe in Genesis and Creationism. This is a huge conversation with both sides able to interpret the available evidence with varying degrees of plausibility. This is an area that is very hotly contested, so I won't go into any depth, instead focusing on your more specific question:

> If we think of human as we have soul, did Neanderthals had one?

Absolutely!

Neanderthals *are* human (at least in the Biblical sense), so they would possess souls exactly as much as you or I. Whether or not you classify neanderthals as a separate "species" could be the subject of vigorous debate, but they are just as much the same biblical *kind* as, for example, *canis lupus* and *canis latrans* (which are capable of interbreeding). Neanderthals are well within the range of variation of the human *kind*, and even atheistic scientists agree that *homo sapiens sapiens* shares DNA with neanderthals. For that matter, there are *living humans* that strongly resemble neanderthals. (Unfortunately, I can't find the reference again, but the man has an article in Wikipedia. Not, of course, claiming that he's a neanderthal, as Wikipedia is firmly committed to the Uniformitarian philosophy, but even so, the visual resemblance is striking.)

Further reading:

- https://www.the-scientist.com/features/neanderthal-dna-in-modern-human-genomes-is-not-silent-66299
- https://www.icr.org/article/humans-neanderthals-more-similar-polar-brown-bears/
- https://www.icr.org/article/dna-proof-that-neandertals-are-just
- https://answersingenesis.org/human-evolution/neanderthal/ (topical index)

Ultimately, from a Biblical standpoint, your premise (that neanderthals are not humans, at least in a Biblical/theistic sense) is faulty.

Comment: You write, "Neanderthals are human (...), so they would possess souls exactly as much as you or I". Does it mean (to you) that Neanderthals descend from Adam and Eve?

Comment: @MigueldeServet, absolutely. Read the linked articles.